# Ehrhart polynomial

Tags: polynomials, convex-polytopes

What is the Ehrhart polynomial of the regular cross-polytope of dimension d? Are there published upper and lower estimates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean the polytope with vertices $(0,\ldots,0,\pm1,0,\ldots,0)$
then it is easily seen to be
$$\sum_{k=0}^d 2^k{d\choose k}{x\choose k}.$$

Comment: I think you mean $2^k$. 

Comment: By the way, you are assuming that Mark wants to work with the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$. The other reasonable choice would be to work with the index two sublattice where the sum of the coordinates is odd. (And, thus, there are no interior lattice points in the polytope.) That should be some simple correction, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Robin or David, Could you give a reference? I did mean Z^d. Thanks! 


Comment: The formula is proved here: http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/noprint.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Robin! It was needed here: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1008.3868

Comment: It can be shown that the Ehrhart polynomial has positive coefficients. However, I don't know an explicit formula that shows this. Rather, one shows that every zero of the polynomial has real part $-1/2$.