# Positivity of the coefficients of the Ehrhart polynomial of a cross-polytope

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes

Question 35996 asks about the Ehrhart polynomial $i_d(n)$ of the
standard regular cross-polytope. It can be defined equivalently by
  $$ \sum_{n\geq 0}i_d(n)x^n = \frac{(1+x)^d}{(1-x)^{d+1}}. $$
It can be shown that the coefficients of $i_d(n)$ are positive, using
Theorem 3.2 of http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/cycles.pdf to show
that all zeros of $i_d(n)$ have real part $-1/2$. Is there some
"positive" formula for $i_d(n)$ that makes it transparent that the
coefficients are positive? Or at least, is there another proof that
doesn't involve the zeros of $i_d(n)$?

Comment: Possibly related?: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308178/cycle-generating-function-of-permutations-with-only-odd-cycles

Comment: @SamHopkins: It is related  but not so useful in answering my question, since positivity is proved by the same Theorem 3.2.

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty: 1/(1-x) has Maclaurin series with positive coefficients, so that so do all its powers (which are known anyway), and multiplying by $(1+x)^d$ preserves this. Since the radius of convergence of the thing on the right is $1$, uniqueness yields the result. Moreover, it also follows that the coefficients form a log concave sequence ... (since those of $1/(1-x)$ and of $1+x$ do).

Comment: Now I see: $i_d (n)$ is supposed to be a polynomial itself in $x$. So ignore my remarks ...

Comment: It would be nice to include  hyperlink to mentioned MO 35996 question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35996/ehrhart-polynomial

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a very simple way to show the positivity.
Define $$f(d,x) = (1+x)^d/(1-x)^{d+1}.$$
Then, by induction
$$ \frac{\partial^t f(d,x)}{\partial\, d^t} = f(d,x)
 \, \ln\biggl(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\biggr)^t.$$
Putting in $d=0$ we have that the Taylor series of $f(d,x)$ with
respect to $d$ is
$$ f(d,x) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{1}{t!} (1-x)^{-1}
   \ln\biggl(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\biggr)^t\,d^t. $$
Both $(1-x)^{-1}$ and $\ln\Bigl(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\Bigr)$ have
non-negative Taylor coefficients, which completes the proof.

In summary, the coefficient of $x^nd^t$ is $2^t/t!$ times
the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$\biggl(\sum_{k\ge 0} x^k\biggr)
  \biggl(\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\biggr)^t.
$$

Answer (score 1):

From the binomial theorem, $(1+x)^d=\sum_{j\geq0}\binom{d}jx^j$ while
$$\frac1{(1-x)^{d+1}}=\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{d+k}kx^k.$$
Therefore, by Cauchy Product formula and as a polynomial in $n$, $i_d(n)$ takes the form
$$i_d(n)=\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{d}{n-k}\binom{d+k}k \qquad \text{or} \qquad
i_d(n)=\sum_{k\geq0}2^k\binom{d}k\binom{n}k.$$
If we employ [Zeilberger's algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeilbergersAlgorithm.html), we find the recurrence
$$
(d+2)\cdot i_{d+2}(n)=(2n+1)\cdot i_{d+1}(n)+(d+1)\cdot i_d(n). \tag1$$
One may now proceed by induction on $d$, with 
$$i_1(n)=2n+1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad  i_2(n)=2n^2+2n+1.$$
**An aside:** Equation (1) reveals $n=-\frac12$ is a root of $i_d(n)$ for all $d$ odd.